# Collections.sort() error occuring while sorting ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort by name ArrayList elements but I couldn't solve problem                            .                          .                                    .                        .                   .                    .

Could someone help?

> ERROR At `case 4: Collections.sort(contact);`
>
> ERROR ***"Required type: List  Provided: List  reason: no
> instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Data conforms to
> Comparable<? super T>"***

below code works fine without sort

```
public class AddressBook {
    private static List<Data> contact = new ArrayList<Data>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menu;
        String choice;
        String choice2;

        System.out.println(" =========================== ");
        System.out.println(" | 0. Exit.                |");
        System.out.println(" | 1. Add contact.         |");
    
        System.out.println(" =========================== ");


        try
        {
            menu = sc.nextInt();
            while (menu != 0) {

            switch (menu) {

                case 1:
                    while (menu != 2) {
                        System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
                        String firstName = sc.next();

                        System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
                        String lastName = sc.next();

                        System.out.println("Enter Phone: ");
                        String homePhone = sc.next();
                        if (homePhone.length()!=11 || !homePhone.startsWith("8")) {
                            System.out.println("Number should start with '8' and has '11' digit" );
                        }else {

                            System.out.println("Enter Email: ");
                            String personalWebSite = sc.next();

                            contact.add(new Data(firstName, lastName,
                                    homePhone, personalWebSite));
                        }

                        System.out
                                .println("Would you like to add someone else? 1: Yes, 2: No");
                        menu = sc.nextInt();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out
                            .println("Enter First Name of contact that you would like to edit: ");
                    choice = sc.next();
                    addressBook.deleteByFirstName(choice);
                    System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
                    String firstName = sc.next().toUpperCase();

                    System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
                    String lastName = sc.next();

                        System.out.println("Enter Phone: ");
                        String homePhone = sc.next();

                        System.out.println("Enter Email: ");
                        String personalWebSite = sc.next();
                        contact.add(new Data(firstName, lastName,
                                homePhone, personalWebSite));
                        break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("------------------");
                    System.out.println("1. Search number: ");
                    System.out.println("2. Search name: ");
                    System.out.println("------------------");
                    int search= sc.nextInt();
                    if(search==1) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Enter Number of contact: ");
                        choice2 = sc.next();
                        addressBook.searchByPhoneNumber(choice2);
                        break;
                    }else {
                        System.out
                                .println("Enter First Name of contact: ");
                        choice = sc.next();
                        addressBook.searchByFirstName(choice);
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    Collections.sort(contact);

                    //ERROR occurring here 




                case 5:
                    System.out.println("This is a list of every contact");
                    System.out.println(addressBook.contact);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("------------------");
                    System.out.println("1. Delete by name: ");
                    System.out.println("2. Delete all: ");
                    System.out.println("------------------");
                    int del= sc.nextInt();
                    if(del==1){
                        System.out
                            .println("Enter First Name of contact that you would like to delete: ");
                    choice = sc.next();
                    addressBook.deleteByFirstName(choice);
                    break;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Successfully Deleted");
                        System.out.println("");

                        contact.clear();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + menu);
            }
            System.out.println(" =========================== ");
            System.out.println(" | 0. Exit.                |");
            System.out.println(" | 1. Add contact.         |");
         
            System.out.println(" =========================== ");
            menu = sc.nextInt();
        }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("This is not an integer");
        }

        System.out.println("Good-Bye!");

    }

    private void searchByFirstName(String firstName) {
        for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Data temp = iterator.next();
            if (temp.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
                System.out.println(temp);
                return;
            }
        }


        System.out.println("No contact with first name " + firstName
                + " was found.");
    }
    private void searchByPhoneNumber(String homePhone) {
        for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Data temp = iterator.next();
            if (temp.getHomePhone().equalsIgnoreCase(homePhone)) {
                System.out.println(temp);
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No contact with number " + homePhone
                + " was found.");
    }


    private void deleteByFirstName(String firstName) {
        for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Data temp = iterator.next();
            if (temp.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
                iterator.remove();
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("No contact with first name " + firstName
                + " was found.");
    }
    private void deleteAll(String all) {
        for (Iterator<Data> iterator = contact.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            iterator.remove();
                return;

        }

        System.out.println("Deleting...");
    }
    private static int[] selectionSortAlg(int[] a, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int iMin = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a[j] < a[iMin]) {
                    iMin = j; // index of smallest element
                }
            }
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[iMin];
            a[iMin] = temp;
            System.out.println("Pass..." + i + "..." + Arrays.toString(a));
        }
        return a;
    }


    public static class Data {
        private String firstName = null;

        private String lastName = null;

        private String homePhone = null;

        private String personalWebSite = null;

        public Data(String firstName,String lastName, String homePhone, String personalWebSite) {
            this.firstName = firstName;

            this.lastName = lastName;

            this.homePhone = homePhone;

            this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public String getHomePhone() {
            return homePhone;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }





        public String toString() {
            return String.format(firstName+" "+lastName+" "+homePhone+" "+personalWebSite);
        }
    }

}

class T {
    private String firstName = null;

    private String lastName = null;

    private String homePhone = null;

    private String personalWebSite = null;

    public T(String firstName,String lastName, String homePhone, String personalWebSite) {
        this.firstName = firstName;

        this.lastName = lastName;

        this.homePhone = homePhone;

        this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getHomePhone() {
        return homePhone;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }





    public String toString() {
        return String.format(firstName+" "+lastName+" "+homePhone+" "+personalWebSite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class `Data` does not implement `Comparable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in this way
`contact.sort( Comparator.comparing(Data::getFirstName) );`

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure, but I think you need to do this(in your case 4):

```
Collections.sort(contact, new Comparator<Data>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Data contact1, Data contact2) {
        return contact1.getFirstName().compareTo(contact2.getFirstName());
    }
});
```

Give it a try, I had used it somewhere else, and it worked. Hope it helps. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you bro!! Your solution also working fine

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Bro how about ```Collections.replaceAll(contact,8,7);``` also same problem as above,  replace all element "8" with "7"?
I'm facing new difficulties. Could u help?

Comment: @User75432132 yes sure. Just tell me what is element "8" ?

Comment: You can't override the method of Collections as they are static and can not be extended, but for your purpose, you can create the following method in your AddressBook Class


.
 `private static void replacePhoneDigit(List<Data> contactList, String oldValue,String newValue){
       
 for (Data contact : contactList){
       
     contact.homePhone = contact.homePhone.replaceAll(oldValue , newValue);
       
 }
    }`

Comment: That's Right @ShehroazAslam

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options whether implement Comparable or provide comparator to sorting function, i.e.

```
Collections.sort(contact, (d1,d2) -> d1.firstName.compareTo(d2.firstName));
```

or

```
contact.sort((d1,d2) -> d1.firstName.compareTo(d2.firstName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `class Data` you implement comparable, look at here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/

```java
public static class Data implements Comparable<Data>
    ...
    public int compareTo(Data m) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: That was a typo I changed to `Data`

Answer (score -1):

Either pass a comparator in sort method or make Data class implement Comparable interface and implement compareTo()

@GiorgosDev gave an example in which data class is expected to implement comparable interface.

Answer (score -1):

Either implement comparable in Data class or pass comparator in sort method. Example Collections.sort(contact, Comparator.comparing(Data::getFirstName));